# Data retrieval - Database VS Programming language

Tags: programming-languages, rdbms

I have been working with databases recently and before that I was developing standalone components that do not use databases.
With all the DB work I have a few questions that sprang up.
Why is a database query faster than a programming language data retrieval from a file.

To elaborate my question further -

Assume I have a table called Employee, with fields Name, ID, DOB, Email and Sex. For reasons of simplicity we will also assume they are all strings of fixed length and they do not have any indexes or primary keys or any other constraints.

Imagine we have 1 million rows of data in the table. At the end of the day this table is going to be stored somewhere on the disk. When I write a query Select Name,ID from Employee where DOB="12/12/1985", the DBMS picks up the data from the file, processes it, filters it and gives me a result which is a subset of the 1 million rows of data.

Now, assume I store the same 1 million rows in a flat file, each field similarly being fixed length string for simplicity. The data is available on a file in the disk.
When I write a program in C++ or C or C# or Java and do the same task of finding the Name and ID where DOB="12/12/1985", I will read the file record by record and check for each row of data if the DOB="12/12/1985", if it matches then I store present the row to the user.

This way of doing it by a program is too slow when compared to the speed at which a SQL query returns the results.

I assume the DBMS is also written in some programming language and there is also an additional overhead of parsing the query and what not.

So what happens in a DBMS that makes it faster to retrieve data than through a programming language?

If this question is inappropriate on this forum, please delete but do provide me some pointers where I may find an answer.

I use SQL Server if that is of any help.

Comment: Caching,Optimizer are the two things which makes Db faster.. If u know to implement in programming language then it could be the best..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of techniques to speed up various kinds of access.  As @Oded says, indexing is the big solution to your specific example:  if the database has been set up to maintain an index by date, it can go directly to the entries for that date, instead of reading through the entire file.  (Note that maintaining an index does take up space and time, though -- it's not free!)

On the other hand, if such an index has *not* been set up, and the database has not been stored in date order, then a query by date will need to go through the entire database, just like your flat-file program.

Of course, you can write your own programs to maintain and use a date index for your file, which will speed up date queries just like a database.  And, you might find that you want to add other indices, to speed up other kinds of queries -- or remove an index that turns out to use more resources than it is worth.

Eventually, managing all the features you've added to your file manager may become a complex task; you may want to store this kind of configuration in its own file, rather than hard-coding it into your program.  At the minimum, you'll need features to make sure that changing your configuration will not corrupt your file...

In other words, you will have written your own database.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is a database query faster than a programming language data retrieval from a file

That depends on many things - network latency and disk seek speeds being two of the important ones. Sometimes it is *faster* to read from a file.

In your description of *finding* a row within a million rows, a database will normally be faster than seeking in a file because it employs *indexing* on the data.

If you pre-process you data file and provided index files for the different fields, you could speedup data lookup from the filesystem as well.

Note: databases are normally used not for this feature, but because they are ACID compliant and therefore are suitable for working in environments where you have multiple processes (normally many clients on many computers) querying the database at the time.

Comment: Great answer. +1 for the Note.

Comment: Thanks Oded, now I get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

...an old one, I know... just for if somebody finds this: The question contained "assume ... do not have any indexes"

...so the question was about the sequential dataread fight between the database and a flat file WITHOUT indexes, which the database wins...

And the answer is: if you read record by record from disk you do lots of disk seeking, which is expensive performance wise. A database always loads pages by concept - so a couple of records all at once. Less disk seeking is definitely faster. If you would do a mem buffered read from a flat file you could achieve the same or better read values.